# PHP to get element from link

Tags: php

I have below code:-

```
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about
```

I want **URL** element that is - http://www.example.com/about

Comment: May I suggest you urlencode the query string parameters? That way you can use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) , however it may not work when you don't have a valid URL present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about';

$url = explode("&url=", $link)[1];
echo $url; //http://www.example.com/about
```

Comment: this won't work properly when the `url` isn't the last query string parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's inbuilt [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) functions.

```
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about';
parse_str(parse_url($link,PHP_URL_QUERY),$url);
echo $url['url'];
```

Comment: this will return the entire query string, so additional parsing is required

Comment: @billyonecan well caught. I should have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about';
$uri=explode("url=",$link);
$uri=$uri[count($uri)-1];

echo $uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSomething($url) {
    if (!(strpos($url, 'url=') !== false)) return false;
    $parse = explode('url=', $url);
    $code = $parse[1];
   return $code;
}

echo getSomething("http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about");
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work even if url is placed somewhere else as parameter

```
$link = 'http://www.domain.com/go.php?id=545&url=http://www.example.com/about';
$url = "";
$params = explode("&", $link);
for($params as $param){
    if(substr($param, 0, 4) === 'url='){
        $url = explode("=", $param)[1];
        break;
    }
}
echo $url; //http://www.example.com/about
```